# Using COUNTIF within VLOOKUP for course completion

Tags: excel-formula

Students are required to complete 4 courses. My query pulls all students by admit term and only includes the courses they've completed. How do I determine which student is missing one or more of the 4 courses?

Need to pull which students do not have all four courses listed.

```
STUDENT ID  NAME    SUBJECT COURSE
1010293 Smith, Joe  ENGL    10803
1010293 Smith, Joe  MATH    10283
1039283 Todd, Don   ENGL    10803
1039283 Todd, Don   MATH    10283
1039283 Todd, Don   ECON    10233
1767289 Park, Kim   ENGL    10803
1767289 Park, Kim   MATH    10283
1767289 Park, Kim   ECON    10223
1767289 Park, Kim   ECON    10233

V Look Up   
ID# 1010293
Name    Smith, Joe
ENGL 10803  complete
ECON 10223  missing
ECON 10233  missing
MATH 10283  complete
```

Comment: Please mock up a small example of the data and expected output.  It will help us help you.  Put this mock up in your original post using [edit] as text so we can copy paste.  If you have trouble formatting properly just paste the values as a table and someone will come along and help format it.

Comment: 1. Your example is missing references.  2. It is always better to copy and paste the values as text in the original post, we can't copy/paste a picture. 3. How do you want the output to look?  Please include that.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do what you want. What seems most straightforward to me, is to create a matrix on a second worksheet. You can use the following steps.

1. Open a new worksheet. The first row could have the possible headers:

   ```
   Student No | Student Name | Engl 10803 | Math 10283 | Econ 10223 | Econ 10233
   ```
2. Copy the list of students' ids in `Column A`. Highlight the pasted ids and clear duplicate numbers by using Excel's remove duplicate function.  `Data>Data Tools>Remove Duplicates`
3. Use `VLOOKUP` if you want to pull in student names. something like `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$10,2,FALSE)` in `B2` of your new sheet.
4. Use an `IF` array function to determine if those students have taken those classes.  Based on your test data, the following function appears to work.

   ```
   =SUM(IF($A2=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,IF(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10&" "&Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10=Sheet2!C$1,1,0),0))
   ```
5. This is an array function, so copy and paste it into `C2`, then submit the function by using `ctrl+shift+enter`. Then you can copy and paste that cells into the range of students `C2:F4` on your test data.

This function works because `Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10&" "&Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10` returns the subject and course number in the same format as the column headers of the second pages.

6. For easy sorting, you can make apply a filter or table format `Home>Styles>Format as Table` or `Data>Sort and Filter>Filter`

Comment: I must not be doing step 5 correctly because my values come back with zero, except for the very first instance.

Comment: Thats my bad. It is 'ctrl+shift+enter` to submit an array formula. I have updated my answer, but below are specific instructions. 

So copy and paste the formula in step 4 into the first cell of your new table. In my mockup, it woudl be `C2`. Then hit `F2` to make sure you have the text of the cell selected. Then hit `ctrl+shift+enter` to submit the formula as an array formula. Then copy and paste `C2` into the rest of the cells on your matrix.